# Optionally pass a parameter of type T to an Action

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, parameters, action

I have a class called `RelayCommand` that inherits the ICommand interface defined like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Base command that executes an <see cref="Action"/>.
/// </summary>
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Members

    // The Action to run.
    private Action mAction;

    #endregion

    #region Events

    /// <summary>
    /// Event fired when the value of <see cref="CanExecute(object)"/> changes.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = (sender, e) => { };

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Default <see cref="RelayCommand"/> constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand(Action action)
    {
        mAction = action;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Command Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// A <see cref="RelayCommand"/> can always be executed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the <see cref="Action"/> of the command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        mAction();
    }

    #endregion 
}
```

I use this class to execute commands throughout the application and sometimes I need to perform `Action`s passing a parameter in the XAML. The problem is that this parameter passing is optional but I can't find a solution that fits with what I'm doing. For example, I have these three commands that basically do the same thing. I set the `PriorityLevel` (`enum` value) to an object through the UI and, depending on which control is clicked, I execute one of the following three methods:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// What to do when the priority of the task is set to <see cref="PriorityLevel.Low"/>
    /// </summary>
    private void OnSetLowPriorityCommand()
    {
        Priority = PriorityLevel.Low;
        PriorityGridWidth = 10;
        PriorityFlagOpacity = 0;
        mIsPriorityChanged = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// What to do when the priority of the task is set to <see cref="PriorityLevel.Medium"/>
    /// </summary>
    private void OnSetMediumPriorityCommand()
    {
        Priority = PriorityLevel.Medium;
        PriorityGridWidth = 10;
        PriorityFlagOpacity = 0;
        mIsPriorityChanged = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// What to do when the priority of the task is set to <see cref="PriorityLevel.High"/>
    /// </summary>
    private void OnSetHighPriorityCommand()
    {
        Priority = PriorityLevel.High;
        PriorityGridWidth = 10;
        PriorityFlagOpacity = 0;
        mIsPriorityChanged = true;
    }
```

As you can see, apart of the first line of the methods, the rest is the same, but I think that it would be better if I keep only one method called, for example, `SetPriorityCommand` that, through a `switch` or whatever, sets the right `PriorityLevel` value. I then consume the `Action`s like this:

```
    SetLowPriorityCommand = new RelayCommand(OnSetLowPriorityCommand);
```

Anyways, in other cases I execute an `Action` without the need of passing a parameter.

Finally, in the XAML I need to execute commands like this:

```
    <Border.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
                      Command="{Binding SetLowPriorityCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Static core:PriorityLevel.Low}}"/> <!-- NOT ALWAYS NECESSARY -->
    </Border.InputBindings>
```

I found plenty of answers about this but none of them seemed to make the use of parameters optional.

How can I adjust the `RelayCommand` class to fit my needs?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You can have two `RelayCommand` one `RelayCommand` that takes an `Action` and then `RelayCommand<T>` that takes and `Action<T>` that you can send a parameter to. Or just take an `Action<object>` and ignore the parameter when you don't need it.

Comment: Or only `RelayCommand<T>`, and when no parameter is required, use `RelayCommand<object>` and ignore the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest change to your code would be just take an `object` parameter and cast that when you call your method. Otherwise you can search the web and find plenty of implementations of `RelayCommand<T>` but here's an example of just using an `object` parameter both when you use the argument and when you don't.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> mAction;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = (sender, e) => { };

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        mAction = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;

    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        mAction(parameter);
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{

    //ignore the argument
    private RelayCommand SetLowPriorityCommand { get => new RelayCommand(_ => SetLowPriority()); }

    //cast and use the argument
    private RelayCommand SetPriority { get => new RelayCommand(priority => SetPriority((int)priority)); }


    private void SetLowPriority()
    {
        //....///
    }

    private void SetPriority(int priority)
    {
        //...//
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is what I was looking for. I've never seen the `_ =>` that allows me to ignore the parameters.